OAuth State Missing or Invalid Error with Google Authentication in ASP.NET Core and Blazor App
I am integrating Google Authentication into my ASP.NET Core and Blazor application to enable users to sign in using their Google accounts. I followed the Google Sign-In documentation and implemented the necessary frontend and backend components. The Google Sign-In button appears and functions as expected on the login page, displaying the user's email and profile picture correctly.
However, when users click the "Sign In" button, they are redirected to my backend endpoint (signin-google), where I encounter an error related to the OAuth state. Specifically, the error message is:
AuthenticationFailureException: The OAuth state was missing or invalid.

I have verified that the g_csrf_token is being set correctly in the cookies, and I have also ensured that the redirect and origin paths are correctly configured in the Google Console. Despite these checks, the issue persists.

Checked Google Console Configuration:

I verified that the redirect URIs and origin paths are correctly configured in the Google Console for my OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.


Integrated Google Sign-In Button:

Added the Google Sign-In button to my login page with the following HTML:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>

<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:5083/signin-google"
     data-auto_prompt="false" class="rounded-xl">
</div>
<div class="flex flex-col w-full items-center">
  <div class="g_id_signin"
      data-type="standard"
      data-size="large"
      data-theme="outline"
      data-text="sign_in_with"
      data-shape="rectangular"
      data-logo_alignment="left">
  </div>  
</div>




Configured ASP.NET Core and Blazor Startup Files:

Reviewed and configured the relevant parts of Startup.cs files in both the ASP.NET Core API and the Blazor App. The files are accessible here:

ASP.NET Core API (Startup.cs)
Blazor App (Startup.cs)





The configuration seems correct based on the documentation and setup steps I followed. However, the persistent OAuth state error suggests there might be an issue with how the OAuth state is being managed or validated.
I’ve tried various configurations and reviewed related documentation but haven’t identified the root cause or found a solution to resolve the error.
ASP.NET Core API (Startup.cs):
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
 
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
 
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty;
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
});
 
var app = builder.Build();
 
app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    // app.MapSwagger().RequireAuthorization();
}
 
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 
app.MapControllers();
 
app.Run();

Blazor App (Startup.cs):
using Frontend.Components;
 
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
 
// Add authorization services
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
 
var app = builder.Build();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
 
 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();
 
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/404");
 
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
 
app.Run();


OAuth flow requires HTTPS to work correctly. Since you mentioned http://localhost:5083 in your data-login_uri, ensure that your application is running over HTTPS during local development. Use https://localhost:5083 instead.

@Rena I've seen many tutorials using http and that works aswell. Is this because my backend is seperated from my blazor that I have to use https?
